# Mac wont load web pages but is connected to the network

Tags: macos, networking

I have a MacBook Pro running OSX 10.9.3 that I use on lots of wireless networks.

Sometimes it will randomly decide that in both Chrome and Safari it wont load any web pages. I can ping the address no problem. Chrome reports that it *could no load the webpage because XXXXXXXX took too long to respond*. It seems to also effect `curl` with it just hanging forever.

It only seems to effect http and https requests and isn't limited to just internet requests, `http://localhost:4000` also fails instead of giving me a localy hosted website. file://blah works fine.

I still receive push notifications from services e.g. facebook

It gets the right IP info from the DHCP servers and can resolve DNS names no issue.

Other devices use the WiFi no problem and the issue persists even when I connect over the wired network.

The MacBook is still connected to the network and can browse cifs shares on various servers.

If I reboot my Mac the issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run any VPN clients? I had the same issue and uninstalling Cisco Anyconnect fixed it for me.

Comment: Nope none at all just a normal network connection. One second its fine and the next it just decides not to load anything

Answer (score 0):

Try a different DNS service like Google's or disable DNS prefetching by going to terminal and executing this command:

defaults write com.apple.safari WebKitDNSPrefetchingEnabled -boolean false

Comment: Will try that next time it happens, although DNS resolution isnt causing me any issues I'm still able to resolve addresses and it happens at random infact yesterday I was using it fine for an hour when it just suddenly stopped when I clicked another link on a website.